# Android-Dynamic TableRow Adding Only 1 Row

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I have created a tablelayout in xml but am adding tablerows dynamically. I thought I had it, but when executed I only get the first tablerow added.

```
TableRow componentDTableRow() {
    Log.d("ADD TO D", "TABLE D");
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
    TableRow newRow=null;


    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        newRow = new TableRow(this);
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            TextView textViewD = new TextView(this);
            textViewD.setTextSize(18);
            textViewD.setWidth(400);
            textViewD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            String test = "TEST";
            textViewD.setText(test);
            newRow.addView(textViewD, params);

        }

    }

    return newRow;

}
```

Part of the xml:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/svD"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="791dp"
    android:layout_height="272dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vsC"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/hsvB">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/hsvD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


        </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</ScrollView>
```

The scollview is in a constraintlayout.
I figure it's something in the loops but I can't determine what. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.add `TableLayout`**

**2.for loop to add `newRow`**

**3.`TableLayout` `addView` in for loop**

You can do like this .

```
Log.d("ADD TO D", "TABLE D");
// add TableLayout
TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableD);
//  add TableRow.LayoutParams
TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(2, 2, 2, 2);
TableRow newRow = null;
// for loop to add newRow
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    newRow = new TableRow(this);
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        TextView textViewD = new TextView(this);
        textViewD.setTextSize(18);
        textViewD.setWidth(400);
        textViewD.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        String test = "TEST";
        textViewD.setText(test);
        newRow.addView(textViewD, params);
    }
    //  tableLayout addView
    tableLayout.addView(newRow);
}
```

Comment: and Sam both thank you for the help. I see now where I was returning newRow I believe I was one loop off. I was returning after all the for loops and wiping out the newRow each time.

Comment: When you use loop for add view .you should add view in the loop .Good luck to you.@snowman

Answer (score 0):

You are simply overwriting `newRow` 10 times:

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    newRow = new TableRow(this);
    for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        //etc
    }

    // Here you need to do something with `newRow`, perhaps add it to your table
}
```